# Inserting data from one hive table to another

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have two tables:

```
TABLE1 with 4 columns (name string, city string, fromdate string, todate string)
TABLE2 with 4 columns (name string, city string, fromdate TIMESTAMP, todate TIMESTAMP)
```

When trying to insert data from TABLE1 to TABLE2 using `insert into...`,
I am getting `NULL` values for datatype changed columns.

Comment: What is the format of strings  `fromdate` and `todate` in `TABLE1`?

Comment: The time stamp format fieds data should be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format, it can be just the date as well. And while inserting string to time stamp cast it to time stamp.

Comment: fromdate,todate-date format(eg:08:12:2018 08:00:00 AM)

Answer (score 0):

When inserting `strings` to `timestamp` Hive converts them. If it is impossible to convert, Hive inserts NULLs. Check strings format. It should be `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.f...]` to be successfully converted to timestamps. See manual here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-TimestampstimestampTimestamps

Answer (score 0):

Check if your TABLE1.fromdate is formatted as a TIMESTAMP
If not try using this:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('your Timestamp', 'yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS'))
```